# How to multiply two string values and store result with "," as a separator?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to multiply two string values and store result with "," as a separator.

Given the inputs:

```
String annualSalary = "200000";
String premium = "0.045";
```

I want the result in the below format:

```
Result = 9000,00
```

Comment: [Decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7)

Comment: You ask for "comma separated format in C#" but you're showing "9000,00" which doesn't show any separation.

Comment: If those are obviuosly **numerical** values - ***WHY*** are you storing those in strings?? Use the **most appropriate** datatype - always - and here, it would be `int` or `decimal` .....

Comment: These variables are used as string somewhere else for my selenium test case, but then I need to multiply those strings and compare the same result which should be in comma separator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using [Decimal.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to convert the strings to a "number", then calculate the result.

The result can be converted to a string using [Decimal.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks(v=vs.110).aspx) with your own culture (IFormatProvider).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-define-and-use-custom-numeric-format-providers.

Comment: I do hate downvotes without a comment. Please own up.

Comment: decimal d = Decimal.Parse(premium); Doing this it shows an error: "Input string was not in a correct format"

Comment: You are most likely running into cultural issues.  Try `Decimal.Parse(premium, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).  And add `using System.Globalization;`